# Spring El Expression

Tags: spring, jsf, faces-config

I'm switching from faces-config to Spring and wanted to know how you can pass a property from one bean to another:

e.g.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="Bean1">

 </bean>
 <bean id="myBean2" class="Bean2">
    <constructor-arg ref="#{myBean1.value}"/>
 </bean>
```

Comment: Can you add a little more context?  Is there a reason you'd do this as opposed to having a property inject the same value into both beans.

Comment: Lets say I have a bean like User and I want to inject user.getLastLoginDate() into a loginBean.setLastLoginDate(Date date). This is quite normal thing to do in a faces-config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to Spring 3.0 which has spring el support

Answer (score -1):

First things first, the purpose of the D.I container is to fully initialize your system prior to execution; that is, all dependencies being set, the app is ready to run.

There are both @property and @value annotations in Spring for similar purposes, but since you want to use and specific bean property value for other bean the best solution would be:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="Bean1">

 </bean>
 <bean id="myBean2" class="Bean2">
    <constructor-arg ref="myBean"/>
 </bean>
```

If you argue that you just want to set the value at instantiation time, and not establish a dependency, then skip the D.I part and set the value directly.